# Scipy: distance correlation is higher than 1

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, correlation

I'm trying to find [distance correlation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Distance_correlation) between columns, look at the code below. Most of time it returns higher than 1 result, which is not possible, because distance correlation is between 0 and 1. You can read about scipy's distance correlation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.correlation.html).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance

x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 10000)
print distance.correlation(x, x**2)
```

> 1.00210811815

What is wrong here or how can I measure it?

**upd1:** [Link to issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5969) on github

Comment: That looks weird. I tried it in R using the energy package and always end up with values around 0.49, so it seems that there is a factor 0.5 missing. No clue... might be worth opening an issue on their github page.

Comment: @Cleb, Sure, I will open an issue

Comment: @Rocketq: why do you think the function is supposed to compute distance correlation --- the documentation says it is computing correlation distance --- which maybe is a completely different thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see why this is a problem according to the documentation.

From the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.correlation.html):

> The correlation distance between u and v, is defined as *1 - \frac{(u - \bar{u}) \cdot (v - \bar{v})}
>           {{||(u - \bar{u})||}_2 {||(v - \bar{v})||}_2}*

By the [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), the expression following the minus sign has an *absolute value that is at most 1*. There is nothing stipulating that it won't be negative, though - in fact, this will happen if the (mean normalized) vectors are anticorrelated.

AFAICT, you should be surprised if you'd get a value larger than 2 or smaller than 0. Using the comment by @Cleb and the fact that the range is [0, 2], I'm guessing that some other packages simply define the distance as *half* this expression.

Comment: It might be that scipy define the term in the other way, but read properties - distance can't be less than 0

Comment: @Rocketq I don't see how it can output anything less than 0, in fact.

Comment: scipy is using the Pearson correlation. Correlation is a measure of similarity, so in order to use it as a distance measure, it calculates 1-p. The one in the reference is a modification of the Pearson correlation that is supposed to detect nonlinear relations as well. So, they are completely different.

Answer (score 5):

**@josef-pkt** 's answer on github is given below:

> It's not a distance correlation which is a nonlinear measure of
>   dependence. e.g. my take
>   http://jpktd.blogspot.ca/2012/06/non-linear-dependence-measures-distance.html
>   However, "correlation" in scipy.spatial.distance.correlation is a bit
>   misleading because according to the formula in the docstring it's a
>   distance measure and not a correlation. perfectly correlated with
>   correlation coefficient equal to 1 has zero distance perfectly
>   negatively correlated with correlation coefficient equal to -1 has
>   maximal distance at 2.

Answer (score 4):

Correlational distance is the inverse of correlation and only looks at the angle/similarity among patterns (sort of like normalization). Correlational distance goes from 0 - 2, with 0 being PERFECT correlation, 1 being no correlation, and 2 being PERFECT ANTICORRELATION. So a small correlational distance value means close together in correlational space (small angular difference). 
Corr = 1 – dist;
Corr dist = 1 – corr; 
so while a high correlation = high relationship; LOW CORR DISTINANCE = high relationship