# Issue : Correlation always gives nan values

Tags: python, scipy, correlation, scipy-spatial

I am a newbie in python and trying to execute the below code :

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import correlation
u1=np.array([10])
u2=np.array([20])
correlation(u1,u2)
```

But I am getting nan, why?

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
dist = 1.0 - np.dot(um, vm) / (norm(um) * norm(vm))
output : nan
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misinterpreted the concept of correlation.

**Correlation indicates the extent to which two or more variables fluctuate together.**

You are passing only single value so it won't be able to determine correlation. 
You need to pass lists with multiple values to be abled to find correlation between them.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import correlation

u1=np.array([10,14,17])
u2=np.array([20,18,12])

print(correlation(u1,u2))
```

Output:

```
1.934719542804484
```

Comment: Correlation is always between -1 and 1, how come this is greater than 1?

Comment: @KMittal Refer this question [scipy-distance-correlation-is-higher-than-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988933/scipy-distance-correlation-is-higher-than-1)